# Execution plan for staging In-Memory tables estimate row count =1

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, sql-server-2017, statistics, memory-optimized-tables

We are using In-Memory tables (durability schema only) as temporary staging tables for part of the ETL process.
the nature of these staging tables is empty most of the time.
The ETL process executed per organization asynchronicity.

Problem:
The execution plan is generated with estimate row number = 1 (probably the table was empty for first execution)

Manually update statistics will not fix the issue since:
the table may be empty or the no record for an organization that ETL will execute first.

I add OPTION recompile to query but still it not stable

I'm looking for correct pattern working with in-memory tables as the Staging table

MS SQL 2017 CU 13
Standard edition

In-Memory table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[process_aggregation_close] ( [organization_id] [bigint] NOT NULL, ...... INDEX [ix_process_aggregation_memory_computer_id_process_id_test] NONCLUSTERED ( [organization_id] ASC, [computer_id] ASC, [process_id] ASC ) )WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON , DURABILITY = SCHEMA_ONLY )
```

Destination Clustered Column Store (disk base)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[process_aggregation_5m]( [organization_id] [bigint] NOT NULL, ....... ) ON [ps_process_aggregation_close]([partkey]) GO CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [IX_process_aggregation_5m] ON [dbo].[process_aggregation_5m] WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0, DATA_COMPRESSION = COLUMNSTORE) ON [ps_process_aggregation_close]([partkey])
```

Thank you
Yuri

Answer (score 3):

Are you using memory-optimized tables, or memory-optimized table **variables**? Memory-optimized table variables suffer from the same issues as "regular" table variables: the cardinality is assumed to be very low.

The other potential issue with using memory-optimized tables as a destination for staging ETL, is that all writes to memory-optimized tables are serial. So you will have to "roll your own" parallelism.

Comment: The parallel load is not an issue for now.

Comment: Are you using memory-optimized tables, or memory-optimized table variables?

Comment: We use memory-optimized tables
But we have a sutuation that ETL will be executed when statistics were recomputed during empty table. in this case out ETL will be stuck

Comment: Are you using native compilation?

Comment: No,
regular store procedure
that make some ETL processing and load to a cluster column store.
Additional issue HUGE one: In case of row estimation = 1 the SELECT INTO is not executed as BULK operation
And all rows inserted to delta store

Comment: I'm assuming SELECT INTO is for a "traditional" table, using the memory-optimized table as the source, because SELECT INTO is not supported for memory-optimized tables. 

Can you post the schema and plans somewhere I can have a look?

Comment: I cannot find any reference that INSERT INTO SELECT is not supported.
Any case when execution plan estimated row count is correct I have BULK compression in the column store (transition to compression is BULK).
When we have estimated row count =1 the all rows insert goes to delta store
I will add both (correct and not )executions plan now

Comment: wrong one: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1wPULq_V

Comment: correct plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkDk_I5OE
This plan load rows to compressed row group directly

Comment: You wrote that "the SELECT INTO is not executed as BULK operation", that's why I responded about SELECT INTO not being supported for memory-optimized tables. But your subsequent comment referenced INSERT INTO SELECT, which of course is supported. Thanks for the plans, however they are estimated and not actual, so they are of limited value. 

The bad plan has a CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint, @organization_id, 0) -- wondering if that's part of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.. Thank you for pointing my attention for the conversation I will fix it. But this is definitely not the issue. I will try to generate actual plan.

Comment: But again the main issue is that with row cout =1 the insert is going to delta store.  I'm looking for correct patterns working with inmemory as staging

Comment: Is the clustered columnstore on a traditional table or a memory-optimized table?

Comment: traditional Disk base cluster column store
In memory staging table :
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[process_aggregation_close]
(
 [organization_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 ......
INDEX [ix_process_aggregation_memory_computer_id_process_id_test] NONCLUSTERED 
(
 [organization_id] ASC,
 [computer_id] ASC,
 [process_id] ASC
)
)WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON , DURABILITY = SCHEMA_ONLY )
GO

Comment: column store destination table:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[process_aggregation_5m](
 [organization_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 .......
) ON [ps_process_aggregation_close]([partkey])
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [IX_process_aggregation_5m] ON [dbo].[process_aggregation_5m] WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0, DATA_COMPRESSION = COLUMNSTORE) ON [ps_process_aggregation_close]([partkey])
GO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91666/discussion-between-nedotter-and-yorik).